# How to map/reduce with sum and max date?

Tags: python, ruby, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a file I need map/reduced where the output needs the sum and the max of a date.  I have the sum part working, however, I'm not sure how to include the max date as part of the reduced output.

The input data looks something like this:

```
ID1,  ID2, date,                count
3000, 001, 2014-12-30 18:00:00, 2
3000, 001, 2015-01-01 10:00:00, 1
3000, 002, 2014-11-18 12:53:00, 5
3000, 002, 2014-12-20 20:14:00, 3
```

My mapper concatenates ID1 + ID2 so that they're grouped. Its output looks like this:

```
key (ID1|ID2), value (count)
3000|001,      2
3000|001,      1
3000|002,      5
3000|002,      3
```

The reducer output looks like this:

```
key (ID1|ID2), value (sum)
3000|001,      3
3000|002,      8
```

What I really need, is output like this:

```
key (ID1|ID2), value (sum), date (max)
3000|001,      3,           2015-01-01 10:00:00
3000|002,      8,           2014-12-20 20:14:00
```

The mapper and reducer are written in Ruby, however, I'll take a working example written in Python (I'll translate it to Ruby).

Here's mapper code:

```
require 'csv'

pattern = File.join(File.expand_path('data', File.dirname(__FILE__)), '*.txt')

Dir.glob(pattern).each do |file|
  CSV.foreach(file, {col_sep: "\t", headers: false}) do |row|
    puts [
           "#{row[6]}|#{row[3].rjust(8, '0')}", # key = ID1 | ID2
           row[7] # value = count
         ].join("\t")
    end
end
```

And the reducer:

```
prev_key  = nil
key_total = 0

ARGF.each do |line|
  line = line.chomp
  next unless line

  (key, value) = line.split("\t")

  # check for new key
  if prev_key && key != prev_key && key_total > 0

    # output total for previous key
    puts [prev_key, key_total].join("\t")

    # reset key total for new key
    prev_key  = key
    key_total = 0

  elsif !prev_key
    prev_key = key

  end

  # add to count for this current key
  key_total += value.to_i

end

# this is to catch the final counts after all records have been received
puts [prev_key, key_total].join("\t")
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the new mapper and reducer based upon the suggestion from the accepted answer:

mapper:

```
require 'csv'

pattern = File.join(File.expand_path('data', File.dirname(__FILE__)), '*.txt')

Dir.glob(pattern).each do |file|
  CSV.foreach(file, {col_sep: "\t", headers: false}) do |row|
    date_time = "#{row[0]} #{row[1]}:00:00#{row[2]}" # %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
    puts [
             "#{row[6]}|#{row[3].rjust(8, '0')}", # key = ID1 | ID2
             "#{row[7]}|#{date_time}", # value = count | date_time
         ].join("\t")
  end
end
```

reducer:

```
require 'date'

prev_key  = nil
key_total = 0
dates = []

ARGF.each do |line|
  line = line.chomp
  next unless line

  (key, values) = line.split("\t")
  (value, date_time) = values.split('|')

  # check for new key
  if prev_key && key != prev_key && key_total > 0

    # output total for previous key
    puts [prev_key.split('|'), key_total, dates.max].join("\t")

    # reset key total for new key
    prev_key  = key
    key_total = 0

    # reset dates array for new key
    dates.clear

  elsif !prev_key
    prev_key = key

  end

  # add date to array for this current key
  dates << DateTime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

  # add to count for this current key
  key_total += value.to_i

end

# this is to catch the final counts after all records have been received
puts [prev_key.split('|'), key_total, dates.max].join("\t")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to put date and count into a pair <date,count> and emit it as a value from your mapper. Then in the reducer extract date and count from the pair value. Sum counts as you did already, and track the max date across input values (per key).